# Error adding loop for in array validation

Tags: javascript, arrays, automation, mocha.js, chai

I'm not able to perform a for loop.
I have an array. Within it, several objects. One of these, I need to make an expect.

I can make several expects, but I believe it is not good practice, since the loop would fit.

But how do I do it?
I can not... =///

```
{
    "testOne": [{
            "situation": {
                "status": "reproved"
            }
        },
        {
            "situation": {
                "status": "rejected"
            }
        },
        {
            "situation": {
                "status": "approved"
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

I need validate each status.

How do I create the loop to go through all items in the array, in this case, status?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are not able to run a for loop directly is because **testOne** array is nested inside an object.

Also, the array itself has further nesting. Therefore the best way in my opinion to deal with this is to use dot on the object and retrieve the **testOne** array and  then use for loop on that or use Array.prototype.forEach( ) function.

I have provided both the approaches below, you may pick whichever one is convenient for you.

```js
const test = {
  testOne: [
    {
      situation: {
        status: 'reproved',
      },
    },
    {
      situation: {
        status: 'rejected',
      },
    },
    {
      situation: {
        status: 'approved',
      },
    },
  ],
};

//retrieving testOne from  test object via dot syntax
const testOne  = test.testOne; 

//Approach 1 - For Loop - on testOne array
console.log('Approach - 1');
for (let i = 0; i < testOne.length; i++) {
  console.log(testOne[i].situation.status);
}

//Approach 2 - Array.prototype.forEach( ) - on testOne array
console.log('Approach - 2');
testOne.forEach(function(obj){
console.log(obj.situation.status)
});
```

Comment: I would avoid the use of arrow functions as they do not work in IE. Use `testOne.forEach(function(obj){ console.log(obj.situation.status)});` instead

Comment: I've changed it to function( ), if OP is using something for transpiling and polyfilling like Bable it wouldn't be a problem, but yes, it would be best to write it in a function declaration instead to avoid issues.

Comment: I've also removed Object destructuring and just using dot syntax now because destructuring is not supported in IE as well (T.T)

Comment: Yes, polyfills are usually best when using any solution that still supports IE. Also, would you look at that, I learned something new today.

Comment: @Link and guys, It worked!
Can I add inside the for loop to scroll only in the x and y statuses?
And I didn't understand much about forEach... =//

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by x and y statuses. If you want to know more about Array.prototype.forEach and other array functions, you will find the details at this url: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1):

Change `testOne` to be an array (right now it's an object) and loop through the array grabbing the status. Look at my fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/bradberkobien/m68sLp03/11/